# Null keys in Java collections that are not sorted

Tags: java, sortedset, sortedmap

Can please someone explain me the following:

it is clear for me why null keys (values) are prohibited in Java sorted collections
But why they are not allowed in HashTable, ConcurrentHashMap and ... Properties

Does it relates somehow to thread-safety?

Is null value allowed/prohibited in CopyOnWriteArrayList? Why?

Thank you

Comment: Because the existence of the `value` is related to the existence of the `key`, otherwise, there would be no point of having the concept of the `HashMap`!

Comment: The docs directly answer your last question.

Comment: A significant reason is just that the Java developers came to believe null was a bad idea in collections :)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 questions here. Both can be answered by reading the docs.

1 - Why HashTable, ConcurrentHashMap and Properties cannot receive "null" as a key?

HashTable:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html

> To successfully store and retrieve objects from a hashtable, the objects used as keys must implement the hashCode method and the equals method.

ConcurrentHashMap:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html

> Conversely, because keys and values in the map are never null, null serves as a reliable atomic indicator of the current lack of any result.

The Properties class extends HashTable, so you already got the reason.

2 - Is null value allowed/prohibited in CopyOnWriteArrayList? Why?

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html

> All elements are permitted, including null.

There is no further explanation on why is that, but I believe it's a design decision.

Answer (score -1):

> ***But why they are not allowed in HashTable***

From the [Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html):

> To successfully store and retrieve objects from a Hashtable, the
>   objects used as keys must implement the hashCode method and the equals method.

of a null referenced object is impossible to get that information(because is null)

> ***Is null value allowed/prohibited in CopyOnWriteArrayList??***

from the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.java#CopyOnWriteArrayList.getArray%28%29)

```
public class CopyOnWriteArrayList<E>
```

---

> A thread-safe variant of java.util.ArrayList in which all mutative
>   operations (add, set, and so on) are implemented by making a fresh
>   copy of the underlying array. ...
>
> ....
>   .....
>
> Element-changing operations on iterators themselves (remove,
>   set, and add) are not supported. These methods throw
>   UnsupportedOperationException.
>
> **All elements are permitted, including null.**

some times it helps reading the doc: